# Unwanted indentation when typing parenthesis

Tags: emacs

I use Emacs in my Mac OS Terminal. It appears that when I type open (shift+9) or close (shift+0) parenthesis, besides the expected display of parenthesis, it also unexpectedly insert many spaces. I've included the effects before and after I type parenthesis as below:

[before typing parenthesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhFBR.png)

[after typing parenthesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8wrF.png)

I'm a newbie to Emacs. So, I'm unsure what the bug is about. Could anyone give me any ideas of how should I proceed to fix this bug? Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: What major mode are you using? Maybe it tries to indent correctly.

Comment: It is not a bug, it's a call to `indent-relative` or `indent-relative-maybe` made by (possibly) your major mode.

Comment: Also vote to move this into [the emacs section](https://emacs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @choroba: Please see the new image. It shows Objc in the next-to-last line. But, I don't know what does that mean... However, the previous lines don't seem to me imply the indent.

Comment: @yorodm: Do you know how to turn this off if I want a quick solution to this issue? Based on all the comments, I'm guessing maybe I need to change major mode. Is it correct?

Comment: I think ObjC is based on `cc-mode` so maybe add this to your `init.el` and eval. `(require 'cc-mode)  (add-to-list 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda () (setq c-syntactic-indentation nil)))`

Comment: @yorodm: It works. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ObjC" in the mode-line means that Emacs decided to use the Object-C mode for that buffer.  This is likely because the `.m` file extension is normally the extension used for Objective-C files.

The Objective-C mode by default reindents the current line for you when you hit some punctuation characters like `(`, `{`, `;` and a few others.  You can disable it, of course, but in your case that'd be working around the real problem which is that your file is not written in Objective-C mode, so you should use *another* mode, which will not only solve this immediate problem, but will give you many other benefits.

I'm not sure what language you're using but I think all you need is one of (or a combination of):

- install the Elisp package which provides support for your language (e.g. mathematica-mode)
- change the extension of your files to that expected by Emacs for that language.
- change `auto-mode-alist` to tell Emacs which mode to use for files ending in `.m`, e.g.:

  ```
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m\\'" . octave-mode))
  ```

Comment: Perfect answer! I tried your item 3 and it worked! Thank you for the explanation and instructions.